# The parameter is not passed from the view to the action

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, view, action

Here is the dropdownlist which contains the parameter (selected value) that I would like to pass to the view:

```
<select id="sltBiblioSite" name="sltBiblioSite">
            <option>Sélectionnez un  BiblioSite</option>
            @*Iterating BiblioSite Model*@
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <option>
                    @item.NomSite
                </option>
            }
        </select>
```

Here is where I tried different things (see commented code below) to pass the parameter to the fucntion:

```
 var selectedBiblioSiteName;

$("#sltBiblioSite").change(function () {

    //selectedBiblioSiteName = $("#sltBiblioSite").val();
    //selectedBiblioSiteName = $("#sltBiblioSite").val().trim();
    //selectedBiblioSiteName = $("#sltBiblioSite option:selected").text();
    //selectedBiblioSiteName = $("#sltBiblioSite > option:selected").attr("value")
    ...
    }
});
```

and here is one of the functions who is supposed to pass the parameter by calling the partial view.

```
    function getReservationTable() {
    $.ajax({
        // Get Reservation PartialView
        url: "/Home/ReservationsToPartialView",
        type: 'Get',
        data: { biblioSiteName: selectedBiblioSiteName },
        success: function (data) {
            $("#reservationDetailTable").empty().append(data);
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("something seems wrong");
        }
    });
}
```

I tried to hardcode the parameter in the action and it's working.
The problem seems to be in the view but I don't know where, please help me to fix this problem.

```
        public ActionResult ReservationsToPartialView(string biblioSiteNom)
    {
        //biblioSiteNom = "La feuille de chene";
        var reservationByBiblio = ReservationLinq.GetReservationByBiblioSite(biblioSiteNom);
        return PartialView("ReservationPV", reservationByBiblio);
    }
```

Comment: `.val()` won't return a value as you aren't setting ANY values in your options (e.g. `<option value="1">Display Value</option>`).

Comment: ok, thank you for this information, I didn't know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't done this in a long time, so I might be completely wrong but I think you are passing wrong parameter name. In your ajax request you have `biblioSiteName` and in your actions its `biblioSiteNom`.

Also try some alert before calling the ajax to see whether the read parameter `biblioSiteName` is correct.